# How do I share an object between two or more WebSocket controllers in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-websocket

I have two controllers, namely `ControllerA` and `ControllerB`. In `ControllerA` I have an object (a `HashMap`) which maps principal names for connected users to their respective usernames:

```
@Controller
public class ControllerA {
    HashMap<String, String> principalToUsername = new HashMap<>();
    ...
}
```

I would like to be able to access this object from `ControllerB`, which is another websocket controller:

```
@Controller
public class ControllerB {
    private String getUsername(String principalName) {
        // I want to access usernames here
    }
}
```

How can I do this? All posts I've read speak about MVC controllers, in which I can use `@SessionVariable` or flash attributes. But how do I accomplish the same with WebSocket controllers?

Comment: If the application runs in more than one VM, then, probably, you'll be better be off with a cache abstraction (using Redis for example). Spring cache: https://spring.io/guides/gs/caching/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an additional `@Component` which keeps the `HashMap<>` and autowire it into both controllers. Be aware that by default, this will be shared by all controllers in the Spring application.

```
@Component
public class UserMap {
    private final Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

    public String getUserName(String userName) {
        return map.get(userName);
    }
}
```

In the controller;

```
private final UserMap userMap;

// autowire in constructor
public ControllerA(UserMap userMap) {
    this.userMap = userMap;
}

private String getUsername(String principalName) {
    userMap.getUserName(principalname);
}
```

Comment: But won't every controller have a different instance of `UserMap` in this case? Will they still be able to access the same `UserMap` object?

Comment: Beans are by default Singleton-scoped, which means there is only 1 instance, which is shared by all that use it.

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful. Once I get the time to try it I will be offering the bounty :)